# AngularJS - Issue with $routeProvider and data-ng-view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, routes, ngroute

I have this following html pages,

1. index.html - has `ng-view`
2. welcome.html
3. app.html - which has many child pages. So need to use `ng-view`

My initial `$routeProvider` is,

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        redirectTo: '/welcome'
    })

    .when('/welcome',{
        templateUrl: 'views/welcome.html',
        controller: welcomeCtrl
    })

    .when('/app',{
        templateUrl: 'app.html',
        controller: mainCtrl
    })

    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/welcome',
    });
```

Now there are multiple child pages within `app.html`. How to add routing for that?

I'm relatively new to AngularJS. I tried to add `ng-view` inside `app.html` and tried to define routes in the same `$routeProvider`, but when I did the same, I got the error, `maximum call stack exceeded` error, and my browser's memory was increasing like anything and it hanged. I am seriously missing something basic

Thanks in Advance for the help.

Comment: Use [Angular UI router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).

Comment: @vucko: Thank you. with `ui-router`, will i be able to use `ng-view` in both the `index.html` and `app.html`?

Comment: Yes, see the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/u18KQc?p=preview).

Comment: @Vucko Thank you. So I understand instead of `data-ng-view` we need to use `ui-view`, and for `data-view`, its `ui-sref`. will try this out.

Comment: Also, you need to use `$stateProvider` instead of `$routeProvider`. See https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki

Comment: @Vucko: Please add answer for this question. I'll accept it. It really helped me, I was not aware of `angular-ui-router` till u suggested, since I'm pretty new to Angular. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use [angular ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router):

> AngularUI Router is a routing framework for AngularJS, which allows you to organize the parts of your interface into a state machine. Unlike the $route service in the Angular ngRoute module, which is organized around URL routes, UI-Router is organized around states, which may optionally have routes, as well as other behavior, attached.